# Easiest way to set custom inputview to all textFields globally

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield, swift4

I created a custom input view for the App I'm currently working on, I can assign this keyboard to a `textField` by doing:

```
textField.inputView = myCustomKeyboard as! UIView
```

Now I just want to switch out all inputViews with my custom inputView, is there a simpler way to do this without having to set the `inputView` on all the textFields separately in my app?

Comment: You can subclass UITextField and set your custom view in initializer. Or you can just write extension with method that is assigning your custom keyboard. And than call this method for every textfield.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[UITextField appearance] setInputView:customeView];
```

or swift:

```
UITextField.appearance().inputView = customeView
```

> Please create custom view and add this line into app delegate did finish launching option

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, Thanks!